# IP Address/Hostname match regex

Tags: sql, regex

I need to match two ipaddress/hostname with a **regular expression**:
Like 20.20.20.20

```
should match with      20.20.20.20
should match with      [http://20.20.20.20/abcd]
should not match with  20.20.20.200
should not match with  [http://20.20.20.200/abcd]
should not match with  [http://120.20.20.20/abcd]
should match with      AB_20.20.20.20
should match with      20.20.20.20_AB
```

At present i am using something like this regular expression: `"(.*[^(\w)]|^)20.20.20.20([^(\w)].*|$)"`
But it is not working for the last two cases. As the **"\w"** is equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_]. Here I also want to eliminate the **"_"** underscore. I tried different combination but not able to succeed. Please help me with this regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

```
(.*[_]|[^(\w)]|^)10.10.10.10([_]|[^(\w)].*|$)
```

I spent some more time on this.This regular expression seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which language you're using, but with Perl-like regular expressions you could use the following, shorter expression:

```
(?:\b|\D)20\.20\.20\.20(?:\b|\D)
```

This effectively says:

1. Match word boundary (`\b`, here: the start of the word) or a non-digit (`\D`).
2. Match IP address.
3. Match word boundary (`\b`, here: the end of the word) or a non-digit (`\D`).

**Note 1:** `?:` causes the grouping `(\b|\D)` not to create a backreference, i.e. to store what it has found. You probably don't need the word boundaries/non-digits to be stored. If you actually need them stored, just remove the two `?:`s.

**Note 2:** This might be nit-picking, but you need to escape the dots in the IP address part of the regular expression, otherwise you'd also match any other character at those positions. Using `20.20.20.20` instead of `20\.20\.20\.20`, you might for example match a line carrying a timestamp when you're searching through a log file...

```
2012-07-18 20:20:20,20  INFO  Application startup successful, IP=20.20.20.200
```

...even though you're looking for IP addresses and that particular one (`20.20.20.200`) explicitly shouldn't match, according to your question. Admittedly though, this example is quite an edge case.